# Angular 6 i18n dynamic translation

Tags: javascript, angular, localization, internationalization

I have a piece of code which I want to be translated using Angular's i18n. This will work but how would I go about translating the 'Enable' or 'Disable' words which are dynamic depending on if the item is disabled or enabled (they are decided if the server returns item.status = 'DISABLED'.

```
<span confirmTitle>
            <ng-container i18n="modal title|Title to disable or enable item@@item.details.modal.title">
            {{ item.status === 'DISABLED' ? 'Enable' : 'Disable'}}
            item?
            </ng-container>
 </span>
```

Comment: That´s also an architectural question. If the backend supplies you with "text", than it may be a good solution that the backend has to deliver it in the correct language. Because if not, than the frontend has to know what possible data the backend may deliver. ---
Beside that: https://angular.io/guide/i18n#select-among-alternative-text-messages  --- you have to declare multiple texts, and then select them by the variable. Warm regards

Answer (score 0):

You could make the code like this,

```
<div *ngIf="item.status=='DISABLED'" >Disabled</div>
<div *ngIf="item.status=='ENABLED'" >Enabled</div>
```

Comment: Works fine in this case, but unfrotunately, does not work for texts that are delivered to other components. (e.g. a table component that has to render table headers)